# Android unable to hide Notification bar

Tags: android, notification-bar

Hidden the notification bar using the theme property in manifest

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

But once i come out of the application using home screen and get back to the app the notification bar didn't get hide.
how it can be solved

Comment: You can do it during `onCreate()` method of your application to hide the titlebar

Comment: Where in your Android Manifest did you put android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" it should an attribute of the application tag

Comment: @BeardFace Yes it is an attribute of application tag only

Answer (score 1):

Try using getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
in onCreate() method of activity.

Comment: i want the notification bar get hidden for the application i tried in this way also but it didn't worked